# Javascript - generate control and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I am trying to generate controls in java script and  append it to a div.
Its working perfectly for textbox and checkbox. But its not working while generating dropdownlist.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tag =
        '<div class="field"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><label class="control-label" style="font-size:16px;font-weight:500;">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CategoryMasterNewModel[i].GroupName)</label></div>' +
        '<div>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CategoryMasterNewModel[i].ID) @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryMasterNewModel[i].Result, (ViewData["ddlist_390"] as List<SelectListItem>), new { @id = Model.CategoryMasterNewModel[i].ID })</div></div></div>'

    var divId = "#innerDiv_" + @Model.CategoryMasterNewModel[i].ParentID;

    jQuery(divId).append(tag);
</script>
```

now when this code gets executed, its creating a problem while evaluation of that tag.

when i checked in console,

The tag is getting generated as follows -

```
var tag = '<div class="field"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><label class="control-label" style="font-size:16px;font-weight:500;"><input id="CategoryMasterNewModel_15__GroupName" name="CategoryMasterNewModel[15].GroupName" type="hidden" value="Manual Override" />Manual Override</label></div>' +
    '<div><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="CategoryMasterNewModel_15__ID" name="CategoryMasterNewModel[15].ID" type="hidden" value="390" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ParentID must be a number." id="CategoryMasterNewModel_15__ParentID" name="CategoryMasterNewModel[15].ParentID" type="hidden" value="207" /><input id="CategoryMasterNewModel_15__Type" name="CategoryMasterNewModel[15].Type" type="hidden" value="Select" /><select id="390" name="CategoryMasterNewModel[15].Result"><option value="yes">yes</option> 
<option value ="no" > no < /option> 
<option value = "others" > others < /option> 
</select></div > < /div></div > '
```

Now because of those last three line are not coming inside that tag, hence its not successfully evaluating  this tag.

Is there any way we can bring all these in on tag only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this way by creating your own script template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tagTemplate">
     <div class="field">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
               <label class="control-label" style="font-size:16px;font-weight:500;">
                 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CategoryMasterNewModel[i].GroupName)
               </label>
           </div>
         <div>
           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CategoryMasterNewModel[i].ID)
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryMasterNewModel[i].Result, (ViewData["ddlist_390"] as List<SelectListItem>), new { @id = Model.CategoryMasterNewModel[i].ID })
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">       
   var divId="#innerDiv_"+ @Model.CategoryMasterNewModel[i].ParentID;
   jQuery(divId).append($("#tagTemplate").html());
</script>
```